# Double Click - Fullscreen

Tags: actionscript-3, double-click

I'm working on a video player and I though that it could be usefull to include the fullscreen's function when the user double click on the stage.

I've done some research but I'm stuck right now because of this line:

```
 player.display.mouseChildren = false;
```

I read somewhere that I have to include this before those:

```
player.display.doubleClickEnabled = true;
player.display.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, doubleClickFS, false, 0, true);
```

However, if mouseChildren is false, the children are not working ^^'.
Do you have an idea to fix this ?

Thank you,
Lea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Here is a cheat solution.</del>

<del>You just make a full size sprite over all layers, and set it to alpha 0.</del>

<del>Add double click listener to the sprite and set `mouseChildren` to false, this won't effect your player.</del>

I just screwed up the event flow in AS3. Here is also a cheat solution.

Make your own `DOUBLE_CLICK` event use `CLICK` event.

```
var lastClickTime:Number = 0;
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var curTime:Number = getTimer();
    if( curTime - lastClickTime < 300 )
    {
        trace("Double Click");
    }
    else
    {
        trace("Single Click");
    }
    lastClickTime = curTime;
});
```

Comment: This will most likely obscure all mouse interaction with the underlying objects.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, it's helpfull :). I already have another problem : "Single Click Single Click" when I double click. It's like doubleclick doesn't exist whereas I write this stage.doubleClickEnabled = true;

Comment: @user3048727 Try to cut the gap time, try 200ms, for me here is Single Click Double Click

Comment: Doesn't work with 200ms, less or more :/. Do you have children in your sprite ? It works if I add mouseChildren = false

Comment: Ok, I found the problem... lastClickTime was into my function ^^'. Thank you, you're the best ;).